# sql , выбор данных за период

Tags: mysql, sql

Как [image: введите сюда описание изображенвведите сюда описание изображенияия]вывести список клиентов с непрерывной историей за год, средний чек за период,  средняя сумма покупок за месяц, количество всех операций по клиенту за период

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct (customer_info_m.Id_client ), 
   avg(customer_info_m.Total_amount) as Srednya_summa_check,
   avg(transactions_info.Count_products * 
   transactions_info.sum_payment) as Srednya_summa_pokupok,
   count(transactions_info.Id_check) as Kolichestva_vsex_operacii,
   transactions_info.date_new as Month
from customer_info_m 
inner join transactions_info 
  on customer_info_m.Id_client = transactions_info.ID_client
where year(date_new)
group by customer_info_m.Id_client , transactions_info.date_new;
```

выводит данные но надо определить что пользователь был активным в течений года (каждый месяц)

Comment: Отформатируйте свой ответ с помощью кнопки Править